Identifying a KMC chain
I am replacing a chain on a bike with a 7 gears Nexus hub gear. In my ignorance, I thought I should have a single speed chain, i.e. 1/8" width. I bought a Shimano CN-NX10, which is marketed to fit the Nexus series. Now that I completed the replacement, I realize the old chain is narrower than the 1/8".
Can anyone help me identify the old chain? It is marked KMC, has the distinct Z logo, and the marking 9L-2. I did find the KMC product page on the Z line, but nothing there says "9L-2".
And does it matter much -- should I get a more narrow chain like 11/128" or 3/32", or is it fine to use a 1/8" anyways?


In my experience, wide chain on narrow cogs works in emergency, but drops easily.
I had to try the combination when the BMX freewheel on my singlespeed bike failed, and I could find only 3/32" replacement. The result was chain dropping every few days until I replaced the chain and chainring with 3/32" ones.

Okay thanks. I'll make sure to order a new chain asap. Any advice how to identify the chain in question?

@LudvigH I wouldn't bother to try to identify the old chain. Singlespeed/internal gear chains come in "wide" and "narrow" variants and if the old chain was narrower than the new one, it means it's "narrow" one. If you want to be sure about the width, measure it with calipers.

I see. Thank you!
